# Differenence between hierarchical linear regression and moderated multiple regression

Tags: regression, interaction, linear-model, multilevel-analysis

What is the difference between hierarchical linear regression and moderated multiple regression? If I have one  and two moderator variables and my models are:

- model 1- IV
- model 2- adding two ModVs
- model 3- adding all the interactive terms,

is my model HLM or MMR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether you use HLM or not is determined by the structure of your data, regardless of whether you want to model moderation or not. If you have a nested data structure (e.g., students nested within schools), you should use HLM, but it does not sound like that is the case. So you should fit (non-hierarchical) MMRs.

If you want to understand MMRs better conceptually, [David Kenny's webpage](http://davidakenny.net/cm/moderation.htm) is an excellent place to start.

Comment: thanks for your reply=) but my concern is " are they using the same approach in SPSS?" because i read lot of paper using HLM and MMR, they look the same. By checking the R2 changes to see if the added variables are significant. So just because of the structure of the data make their names different?

Comment: @Masato: +1 for your answer to this badly formulated question.

Comment: I know it is confusing, but HLM (or mixed-effects modeling) and hierarchical multiple regression (HMR) are different things entirely. The latter is a model-fitting strategy to see whether including certain predictors will change R^2 sufficiently or not. On the other hand, MMR simply is a type of regression models that have moderator variables and their interactions with other predictors. You can use HMR to see if including all the interactive terms (model 3) will significantly improve model fit or not over model 2.
@MichaelMayer: Thanks for your kind words.